# Unable to display PHP errors in my pages

Tags: php

I just started to developp in a company. I'm totally unable to display PHP errors in my page so it is so annoying to make it work.

I have set :

```
display_errors = on
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Do you have any idea about it ? Thanks!

Comment: have you restarted your apache server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you made the changes in a php.ini, you should restart Apache.

If you made the changes in an Apache .conf file, you should reload Apache.

You may also add this code as the first line of the first file:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

Be sure to remove this setting from everywhere before using the code in a production environment.